# Hosting a public socks proxy with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, socks

I've been at this all day. Time to get help.
I'm trying to figure out how to HOST a PUBLIC socks proxy server in Linux. I'm attempting to accomplish this with VirtualBox, which makes it even harder. I don't want to install Linux on my computer, but I need to figure this out.
I've researched for hours and all I've found is hundreds(literally hundreds) of guides telling you how to connect to a socks proxy server. -__-
I've been experimenting with it for the last 5 hours, I've come pretty close but I keep coming up with new problems.
If you've ever accomplished this, or have a link to a guide for this, I'd be so grateful. Thank you.
Thanks. -Alex

Comment: Please follow this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827342/updating-socks-proxy-via-apt-conf-doesnt-update-network-managerproxy-section It should help.