# Updating SOCKS proxy via apt.conf doesn't update Network Manager>>Proxy section

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, proxy, apt, socks

**Os:** Ubuntu 16.10

**What I'm trying to do:**

I've got external socks v5 server. I want to *send all local WEB traffic to socks server by doing this:

1. ssh -D 1337 -f -C -q -N admin@socks_server_ip; #Connection no issues here
2. ps aux | grep 1337 # I see PID related to this connection, no issues here as well
3. Update /etc/apt/apt.conf as:

**Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://user:pass@host:port/";** #No issues in updating apt.conf as well

**Problem:**

When I'm done succesfully editing apt.conf file, I should be able to see changes in Network >> Proxy section listing socks proxy details something like this:
[image: Network]

BUT, even after updating apt.conf, I see this:
[image]

And I can't access internet until or unless I **manually** set Network >> Proxy details. Anybody have any idea why this is happening?? Please suggest any solutions if possible. Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su].

Answer (score 1):

Editing `apt.conf` changes the proxy just for the APT (package manager). If you want to set up the proxy system-wide, you really need to go to Network >> Proxy  and set that manually.

Comment: Thanks Jakuje. Do you happen to know any terminal cmd to update proxy in Network>>Proxy section?

Comment: No. But there will most probably be some D-Bus message that would be able to set this configuration.